# Load csv with Graphenedb

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphenedb

I tried to import files to the localhost with the following Clause and has been successful:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/Users/studio/Desktop/nodiToscana.csv' AS row 
CREATE (:Startup {startupName: row.Startup});
```

when I tried to use the same expression on Graphene it gave me error

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the file path you specified (`/Users/studio/Desktop/nodiToscana.csv`) does not exist on the GrapheneDB server. You need to provide a URL to a file that is accessible to the GrapheneDB server. Two easy ways to do this:

- host the file on dropbox and use the public URL
- use a google spreadsheet as described [here](http://blog.bruggen.com/2014/07/using-loadcsv-to-import-data-from.html)

Comment: Thank you very much.

USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18705960/nodiToscana.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ',' CREATE (:Startup {startupName: row.Startup});

I tried both the first and the second method but both did not load data. Particularly using dropbox get this error: Could not create token